# Temperance leading to madness

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, roleplaying, mage-the-awakening, virtues-and-vices

Premise: I'm playing a courteous and professional burglar in a mixed (mage and human) nWoD campaign. I am one of two non-mages is a party of 5. I play the only sane character. My character has temperance as virtue and envy as a vice.

Situation: The other characters regularly abuse their power, fame, and status to the detriment of anyone unfortunate to be caught up in their mess. I play my character as both disgusted by their misuse of power and envious of their abilities. The situation is starting to drive my character crazy.

**Question: Where do I go to from here?**

Comment: I'm thinking of letting my voice of reason fade away and buy up our home-ruled version of the arcane merit, but that may not be the best/funnest role playing option.

Comment: Hi, Overthinks! Can you clarify your question a little bit? Are you looking for advice on how to play a character that's being driven crazy, or how to change the ways your fellow players play, or how to deal with being the one sane person in a troupe of madcap mages? Where do you want to be at the end?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. Unfortunately, help-me-with-idea questions don't really work as Stack questions. As a rule they result in a list of ideas with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This would need to be revised to be about solving a *specific* concrete problem to be answerable in our Q&A site format. Otherwise, you may just actually want a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449) instead of a Stack.

Comment: Hello Jadasc. I am looking for suggestions on where to go to from here. My comment in the question was a possible direction I could take this role play idea, but I'm hoping that someone here could think of a more engaging direction to go with. I have no goal to this beyond some fun role playing.

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I have to concur with @SevenSidedDie in that this thing may not be right for our site.